# login problem, does anyone know how to solve this?

Tags: login, bug-reporting

Every time I log into Ubuntu, after I put in my password this motherboard's screen shows up(the same one we see when we turn on the computer)

[[image]

and then returns to desktop as you can see in the following video.

I'm using x11 instead Wayland. My graphics card it is a 1660, and drive version: NVIDIA Corporation TU116.

I didn't have this problem before, it started a few weeks ago.

https://youtu.be/_hnh2Gyy4J0

Does anyone know what could be causing this? How can I solve it? Thank you

[image]

Comment: Are you using Wayland or X11? Which graphics card and driver?

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you using? Did it work before and does not know or has it never worked? What do you mean by motherboards screen, what does it say or look like? Most people will not look at a video.

Comment: @David Why wouldn't they look at the video? It's only an 11 second video.

Comment: @karel I have seen that same comment many times and I know I would not change screens and run a video of any length. Also how would I have known it was 11 seconds? I see you converted it to run inline. So how is my comment a problem?

Comment: @muru I'm using x11 instead Wayland. My graphics card it is a 1660, and drive version: NVIDIA Corporation TU116.